# How to enlarge individual cells while scrolling in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UICollectionView` which has scrolling direction of horizontal. What I want to achieve is that when the `UICollectionView` is scrolled I want individual cells to enlarge there size. For example like the album Art work view in old iOS music app.

Comment: Ok, so you have a requirement, but do you have a problem? What code did you try to solve it with (show us)?

Comment: Right now i just have a UICOLLECTIONVIEW with a scrolling direction of Horizontal. I really have no idea how to achieve it. And also i just started coding for IOS. So if you could point me in the right direction it will great. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Alishareef this can be achieved with a custom UICollectionViewLayout. There are lots of examples in the wild, and I believe Some from Apple too. Do some research and write some code, and if you're still stuck, post your code and I'm sure someone will help

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to "OLD IOS music app" art work view, then the easiest way I think would be to implement "scrollViewDidScroll" delegate method, then inside of "scrollViewDidScroll" get all visible cells of your collection view, and depending on their offset set CGAffineTransformScale.